# VSCode tmLanguage.json issue: how to prevent nested block comment?

Tags: regex, visual-studio-code, comments

I want to support a customized language which does not support nested block comment, i.e., the following code should be considered as comment:

```c
/* /*  */
```

The tmLanguage.json for my VSCode extension uses:

```json
  "comment": "Block comment",
  "name": "comment.block.cxm",
  "begin": "/\\*",
  "end": "\\*/",
```

It failed and it requires another "*/" to end the comment.
I tried

```json
  "begin": "/\\*[\\s\\S]*(?=\\*/)",
```

it works for the above code, but it can't handle multi-line case:

```c
/*
/*
*/
```

Can any one help? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some researching in [TextMate](https://macromates.com/manual/en/language_grammars), the tmLanguage.json defaultly does not support nested pattern.
I incorrectly used:

```json
"block_comment": {
    "comment": "Block comment",
    "name": "comment.block.cxm",
    "begin": "/\\*",
    "end": "\\*/",
    "patterns": [
    {
        "include": "#block_comment"
    }
}
```

I removed the "patterns" field and now the nested block comment is not allowed.